# Console tabbing through previous commands in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, console, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide

In PyCharm, using the Python console, I often press the up arrow to go through several previous commands. This is tedious if the commands are many lines long (for instance, the result of sending a long routine from a file to the console).

In IntelliJ, you can press `Command + up` to go to previous command without moving through all the lines of the current command. How can I do this in PyCharm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this functionality by [configuring two keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html) that are not set by default. Go to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Keymap` `>` `Other` and add the keyboard shortcuts right clicking on `Next Entry in Console History` and `Previous Entry in Console History`.

[image: screenshot settings keymap]

For the shortcuts to work you have to configure them before launching the console or press the `Rerun` icon in the console toolbar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> if it's already running.

You can also choose previous console history commands by clicking the [Browse Query History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-consoles.html#buttons) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in the console toolbar.

[image: screenshot console history]